# Use _sortBy of lodash to sort an array by a different field

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

Having an array of objects like this:

```
myArray = [
            {AType: "aaa", Description: "De", …},
            {AType: "bbb", Description: "Hi", …},
            {AType: "ccc", Description: "Un", …},
            {AType: "ddd", Description: "Hw", …}, 
            ];
```

it is sorted by `AType` but I want to sort it by `Description`.

I tried to use [sortBy from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sortBy):

```
import _sortBy from 'lodash/sortBy';

mySortedArray = _sortBy(myArray, s => s.Description);
```

It doesn't do what I would expect, the result looks like : `[Array(4), Array(3), {…}, {…}]`

Any ideas how to sort it by that field but also not to modify anything else inside the array?

Comment: it works fine. maybe the import is wrong ...

Comment: (catching up from previous questions) AngularJS `orderBy` had a valid solution, here is an [example in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lmyoSRbgr9OBrVl0Oufv?p=preview)

Comment: @NinaScholz you're right, the import was not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue is on your end. Also for a simple sort like this you don't need an arrow function, just the property name.

```js
myArray = [
    {AType: "aaa", Description: "De"},
    {AType: "bbb", Description: "Hi"},
    {AType: "ccc", Description: "Un"},
    {AType: "ddd", Description: "Hw"}
];

mySortedArray = _.sortBy(myArray, 'Description');

console.log(mySortedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```